# Issue With PHP Function Load

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a project built with [***Codeigniter3***](https://codeigniter.com/download), I have created a controller which have multiple `methods/functions`.

- **Function 1**, this function do some work it contains some logical    loops.
- **Function 2** when accessing this or any other function it keeps
  hanging until the function 1 finishes, then it loads.

This is the code of the Function 1:

> ***Note***: the function works fine the only problem is when it runs, I can't access other functions in the controller until it finishes the
>   work, So what i expect is to be able to access other functions during
>   the run.

I tried to create new function that has loops and ran it, I was able to access other functions during the run!

I couldn't find out what causes the issue.

Comment: I forgot to paste the code: https://pastebin.com/ZYr3APTP

Comment: Edit your question and then paste it

Comment: Put only the relevant code directly into the question (and format it as code using the `{}` button from the question editor toolbar).

Comment: when you hanging what you mean by that. can you explain that.

Comment: Unlike Node.js, PHP is a synchronously processed language. You cannot execute code while other code is still running (unless you use multithreading, but that has its own issues).

Comment: the function 2 keeps loading until the function 1 finishes the execution then it loads the content.

Comment: Your scripts works fine. You mentioned you are using CI 3 use profiling and check if there is any delay due to presence of function1

Comment: @Dormilich, As i mentioned in the post i tried to create new function I put some loops in it while it runs, I was able to access other functions!

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy Thanks for the comment, any idea how can I apply this checks?

Comment: $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); try this

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy I have got this result: https://pastebin.com/mPADe8jG, do you have any solution to customize the loops, I think it has a bug on the way it is written.
- because when I created a new function i put some loops in it, I was able to access other functions in the controller.

Comment: have you checked the Total Execution Time  for with and without function 1.

Comment: I pick up one function which contains only the view it executed at : 0.0513 seconds, but the function 1 took 38.1799 , I guess it's fine as it has so many loops and curl calls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169657/discussion-between-petr-and-prasanna-puttaswamy).

Comment: I have did some tests I found out its because of the remote calls get_headers and curl i am doing in the code which take time to wait for the remote server to respond, but still these remote calls are necessary for my project .. is there anyway to fix the issue ?

Comment: @Dormilich is it possible to apply stream_select in the code for this issue?